# Error al ejecutar proyecto maven en spring tools : Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, eclipse, maven

Cuando ejecuto un proyecto maven recién importado en spring tools, me da el siguiente error:

```
****Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2022-04-08 11:10:46.259[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m18396[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Action:
**Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Hiciste lo que dice el mensaje? Te está describiendo lo que debes hacer. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Muestra tu `application.properties` y tu `pom`. Si estás configurando una base de datos, te falta especificar una `url` e incluir el driver en tu `pom`. Si no estás configurando nada, probablemente agregaste en  `application.properties` alguna configuración incompleta del `datasource` que hace que spring intente configurarlo y falle.

Comment: hola, application.properties lo tengo vacio , y el pom lo tengo con las dependencias Spring Data JPA, MySQL Driver, Spring Web

Comment: @fernando ¿cómo estás configurando el `Bean` del `DataSource`?. Supongo qué el driver de `MySQL` lo tendrás por algo ¿no? No tiene sentido tenerlo sin una conexión a una base de datos. Si no estás conectándote a una base de datos, remuévelo y prueba. Si estás conectándote, por favor, presiona `Editar` en tu pregunta y adjunta el código del `Bean` donde configuras el `datasource`.

Comment: ya lo pude resolver, gracias!